# Trouble making an executable jar with lwjgl

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, lwjgl

When I try to make an executable jar in NetBeans I get this error:

`C:\lwjgl\lwjgl-2.8.5\res is a directory or can't be read. Not copying the libraries.`

The res folder holds files like jpgs and wavs that the program relies on to function. I'm using lwjgl, would that be part of the problem? What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to run from a .jar file and it's giving you this issue but not from the IDE, you should just be able to open the jar file with winrar or another similar program and just copy/paste the whole res directory into the jar file.

You then use the following code to retrieve your file in the program (instead of where you're retrieving from "C:\lwjgl\lwjgl-2.8.5\res":

```
ResourceLoader.getResource(stringLocationToResource);
```

This will return the resource that you were trying to get.

The file has to be next to your src file, and not in it.